# How can I add an active class to img tag which is wrapped inside a Navlink?

Tags: css, reactjs

So the below code works fine. It will show active class when dashboard is active but how can I make active for img tag and change its color when dashboard is active?

```
    <div className="links-nav">
        <NavLink className="item" activeClassName="active" to="/dashboard">
              <img
                src="/images/svgs/dashboard.svg"
                className="home"
                alt="home"
              />
              <span
                className="nav-content"
                onClick={(event) => this.navLinks(event)}
              >
                Dashboard
              </span>
            </NavLink>
       </div>   
        
   .links-nav .active {
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #000000;
    }
.link-nav .home .active {
  background :#0000FF
```

.home .active is not working I am new to css and react.Can anyone help me with my query?

Comment: Try this .link-nav .active .home  {
  background :#0000FF
}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to update the background of the image (`.home`). Using the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) selector ( ) will match the *second* selector if they have an ancestor matching the first selector. Your selector has swapped the "home" and "active" classnames.

```
.links-nav .active .home {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-add-an-active-class-to-img-tag-which-is-wrapped-inside-a-navlink]

Comment: thank you for your efforts. Can we change color of the svg which is inside a img tag but not background color.I have added my svg icon in code and tried with my knowledge.https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-an-active-class-to-img-tag-which-is-wrapped-inside-a-navlink-forked-logdf?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: @AkhilRaghav Yes, generally via the `stroke` and `fill` CSS rules. If you could get a sample codesandbox up with an SVG I can help.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-an-active-class-to-img-tag-which-is-wrapped-inside-a-navlink-forked-logdf?file=/src/styles.css  please look into this link

Comment: @AkhilRaghav Sorry, I didn't see that you were rendering an SVG into an img tag, it's not possible to then edit the fill/stroke as it is now an image asset versus SVG markup. If you had the capability to move the SVG *into* your project you can import it as a react component and apply CSS. https://codesandbox.io/s/import-svg-and-style-with-css-i8brz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark